# Why os.path.join() command behaves differently in two situations?

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, directory, path

I have`os.path.join` command in a big code in Jupyterlab. I put a try-except block & found that it doesn't join anything. BUT when I put the same command in a separate Jupyterlab notebook it joins normally. Why so? Please throw some light.

My path is `'./tmp/deeptest-trpo/'`

```
def get_monitor_files(path: str) -> List[str]:
    
    ##print(path) gives ./tmp/deeptest-trpo/ i.e. without the ''. Is this the cause?

    try:
        os.path.join(path, "*" + "monitor.csv")
    except:
        print('not joining')  #always reaches here
 
    return glob(os.path.join(path, "*" + "monitor.csv"))
```

**BUT BUT** when I do it separately, it works normal!

```
import os
pathh='./tmp/deeptest-trpo/'
os.path.join(pathh, "*" + "monitor.csv")
```

###OUTPUT IS `'./tmp/deeptest-trpo/*monitor.csv'`

If it helps, this get_monitor_files is an inbuilt function. I extracted parts of it to analyze the above discrepancy.

Comment: The except block is hiding the actual error.  Take out the try/except and just call os.path.join normally.  This way you can see the actual exception, and hopefully it will explain things.

Comment: Use ```except Exception as e``` and then in the exception block use ```print(e)``` and that should help to understand what is going wrong.

Comment: My guess is the variable ```path``` while type-hinted as a string, is not actually being passed as a string, and when you try and use the ```+``` operator on the "*" and the variable ```path```, which is not a string, it fails. But that's an entire guess without seeing the error.

Comment: The `return` statement has an identical call to `os.path.join()`, so it should throw an exception also...

Answer (score 0):

Using python 3.8.9 on an M1 mac, I get no errors running:

```
def get_monitor_files(path: str) -> 'list[str]':
    try:
        p = os.path.join(path, "*" + "monitor.csv")
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    else:
        print(p)
 
get_monitor_files("./tmp/deeptest-trpo/")
```

and it prints `./tmp/deeptest-trpo/*monitor.csv` without a problem. I would handle the exception as I do so you can see what is going wrong.

Edit: copying my comment from above:
My guess is the variable `path` while type-hinted as a string, is not actually being passed as a string, and when you try and use the `+` operator on the `"*"` and the variable `path`, which is not a string, it fails. But that's an entire guess without seeing the error.